# BigQuery - Get the display name of scheduled query from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema

I am trying to figure out the display name of scheduled query from BigQuery information_schema. The only available information in information_schema is `labels.key="datasource_id"` and `labels.value="scheduled_query` which allows me to identify that it is a scheduled query. But how can I figure out the display name of that scheduled query?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. The "display name" is metadata on Scheduled Query which doesn't propagate to the query Job that was created by Scheduled Query.